# Angular 8 Multi phrase search using ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf, pdf.js, phrase, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I'm working on an angular8 application and displaying a PDF using ng2-pdf-viewer library. Currently, I'm able to search the PDF for a single phrase using the code below.

```
searchQueryChanged(searchStr: string) {
    if(searchStr != null && searchStr.length > 0) {
      console.log("searchStr1 ::: ", searchStr);
      this.pdfComponent.pdfFindController.executeCommand('find', {
        highlightAll: true,
        caseSensitive: true,
        findPrevious: false,
        phraseSearch: true,
        query: searchStr
      });
    }
  }
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to **search for an array of strings/phrases and highlight them all at the same time using ng2-pdf-viewer library** or is there a much better way to highlight multiple strings in a given PDF.

Thanks,
Ravi Teja Talari

Comment: did u get how to do it by any chance?

Comment: sorry I know this post is old did you get it done by any chance ?