# Search with multiple phrases with ng2-pdf-viewer pdf.js

Tags: full-text-search, pdf.js, angular13, ng2-pdf-viewer

There is a similar question that was asked about this subject a long time ago but it looks that nobody has found a solution yet: [Angular 8 Multi phrase search using ng2-pdf-viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652409/angular-8-multi-phrase-search-using-ng2-pdf-viewer)

I'm basically trying to do the same but with more specs.

**Case 1.** Input single quoted phrase: `"is an angular component"`

Expected highlighted:

> Ng2-pdf-viewer **is an Angular component** that enables users to view PDF
> files in a web application. It utilizes the PDF.js library to render
> PDF files and provides various features, such as zooming, printing,
> and searching for text within the PDF document.

**Case 2.** Input multiple quoted phrase: `"library to" "view PDF files"`

Expected highlighted:

> Ng2-pdf-viewer is an Angular component that enables users to **view PDF**
> **files** in a web application. It utilizes the PDF.js **library to** render
> PDF files and provides various features, such as zooming, printing,
> and searching for text within the PDF document.

**Case 3.** Input multiple not quoted words: `printing zooming text pdf`

Expected highlighted:

> Ng2-**pdf**-viewer is an Angular component that enables users to view **PDF**
> files in a web application. It utilizes the **PDF**.js library to render
> **PDF** files and provides various features, such as **zooming**, **printing**,
> and searching for **text** within the PDF document.

**Case 4.** Input multiple not quoted words with a single quoted word: `printing zooming text pdf "component that"`

Expected highlighted:

> Ng2-**pdf**-viewer is an Angular **component that** enables users to view **PDF**
> files in a web application. It utilizes the **PDF**.js library to render
> **PDF** files and provides various features, such as **zooming**, **printing**,
> and searching for **text** within the PDF document.

This is the implementation I got so far:

```
searchOccurrences(search = ''): void {
        if (search) {
            this.searchWord = search;
        }
        let searchWords: string[] = [this.searchWord];
        this.phraseSearch = false;

        if (this.searchWord && this.searchWord.startsWith('"') && this.searchWord.endsWith('"')) {
            // Split the search term by double quotes and remove empty strings
            const phrases = this.searchWord.split('"').filter(s => s.trim() !== '');
            this.phraseSearch = true;
            searchWords = phrases;
        }
        for (const phrase of searchWords) {
            this.pdfViewer.eventBus.dispatch('find', {
                caseSensitive: false,
                findPrevious: false,
                highlightAll: true,
                phraseSearch: this.phraseSearch,
                query: phrase
            });
        }
        // reset matches
        this.totalMatches = 0;
        this.currentWordIndex = 0;
        this.matchIndex = 0;
        this.currentPageIndex = this.currentPage - 1;
        this.matches = [];
        this.pdfViewer.eventBus.on('updatefindmatchescount', data => {
            this.updateValues(data);
        });
    }

    updateValues(data: any): void {
        this.totalMatches += data.matchesCount.total;
        this.matches = this.matches.concat(data.source._pageMatches);
        this.lastPageMatch = this.getLatestPageOnMatches();
        this.firstPageMatch = this.getFirstPageOnMatches();
    }
```

The problem with this implementation is that in the cases 2 and 4, the last search replaces the highlight and results of the others.